# Zxing java not reading valid qr code

Tags: java, zxing, qr-code

I have been using googles zxing library trying to decode a valid qr code and am having difficulty figuring out why its not scanning. The image below has the code. I tried this code on http://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx after i noticed it failed in my application and I saw that the website was also not reading it.

I tried the code on http://blog.qr4.nl/Online-QR-Code_Decoder.aspx and it was able to read the file fine. Is this just something I chalk up to the fact that noise can sometimes cause an algorithm to omit a valid solution? Is there something I should be configuring in zxing to get this to work? 
[image: Here is the qr code]

Comment: Have you switched logging to DEBUG or TRACE and looked at the logs? **This question is probably insoluble without additional diagnosis & information from you.** Make sure you've downloaded the source code & linked it from your project, so you can see & debug around where it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The online decoder rejects large images to prevent DoS attacks, and this is almost 9MP. That's why it is rejected. It scans fine otherwise by the library. Try it locally or using your phone.

Comment: Hey you are right I reduced the size and it worked fine in the online decoder. I must be using some default limitations on the library side because its failing on the library side as well. Thanks for helping me identify the issue I had only notice dthe <2MB limit on the zxing site not hte <8MP